# Loadrunner - Impossible to run a test in Performance Center

Tags: loadrunner

I this error message everytime I try to launch my test in performance center even tough the test works perfectly on my local machine in VuGen. Here's the error message :

"***Run test failed. Reason: 'Vugen error code: -81021'
Run 273 (timeslot 5603) changed state from Initializing to Run Failure.
Load Test '' failed (Run ID 273).
Timeslot ID '5603' was closed***"

Does anyone already encountered this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lost your window of opportunity for you to run your test.  Speak to your Performance Test Admin to schedule another window of opportunity to execute your test.